# Yeoman npm install fails on Windows

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman

I am trying to install the Yeoman generator on my 64 bit Windows 10 machine using npm. It continuously fails with the following errors. I am running as administrator and have tried a number of different combinations of switches and am even running the latest version of Node (6.2.0). Any ideas?

```
npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.4: cross-spawn no longer requires a build toolchain, use it instead!
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into  npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\paulsumm\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! node v6.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.0
npm ERR! path C:\Users\paulsumm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\cli.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall chmod

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'C:\Users\paulsumm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\cli.js'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'C:\Users\paulsumm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\cli.js'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install the previous version:

```
npm install -g yo@1.8.1
```

Comment: New version has some problems